# How to insert data into excel in Horizontal?

Tags: python-3.x, xlwt

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok=True)

data = (
[(1,),(2,),(3,)],
[('a',),('b',),('c',)],
[('e',),('f',),('g',)],
)
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    for r_num, r_value in enumerate(value):
        ws.write(r_num, index,r_value[0])

wb.save('test.xls')
```

My result is as below.  But how can I insert mydata into excel in Horizontal?
[image: my result]

Comment: Use the same `r_num` for every `ws.write` call?

Comment: My answer is wrong. It can only insert date in vertical way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question the right way, you want the numbers to be in the top row. If so, you can just replace `ws.write(r_num, index,r_value[0])` with `ws.write(index, r_num,r_value[0])`.